# Is there a way to get the metadata(like hight, framerate, bitrate) of an MPEG file?

Tags: java, video, metadata, mpeg

For part of a private project I am working on, I want to get the height, width, bite rate, FPS of an MPEG in Java. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum... I'm not an expert in the subject but I would start by taking a look in the source code of some Open Source decoders:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/javampeg1video/
- http://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/~jan/MPEG/MPEG_Play.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264avcjavaenco/

Cheers,

Comment: Well I'd start by looking at the correct ISO standard (there's always some pdf floating around on the web in my experience) if I wanted to implement it myself ;) But I'd think using an existing solution such as one of those you linked is the much better approach anyhow

Comment: Those open source projects give me what I need, thank you very much.

Comment: Jamie. I'm glad to be of service. If you think this closes the question, please don't forget to accept the answer.